# How can I rename default session cookie names in servicestack

Tags: c#, security, cookies, servicestack, session-cookies

ServiceStack has the default cookie names
"ss-id" "ss-pid" and "ss-opt" defined in SessionFeature.cs

Is there a way to change the default names to something else?

The configuration code in HostConfig doesn't seem to reference it.

Would appreciate any tips/pointers.

Answer (score 4):

As you've noted in the [SessionFeature.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/SessionFeature.cs) code the cookie names are defined as `const`, and are not user configurable.

You could however use filters to change the cookie names to something more suitable on request and response. Add to your configure method:

```
const string mySessionIdentifier = "mySessionId";

// Converts incoming requests with "mySessionId" cookie to "ss-id"
PreRequestFilters.Add((IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes) =>
{
    var cookie = httpReq.Cookies[mySessionIdentifier];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        httpReq.Cookies.Remove(mySessionIdentifier);
        httpReq.Cookies.Add(ServiceStack.Keywords.SessionId, cookie);
    }
}


// Converts responses with outgoing cookie "ss-id" to "mySessionId"
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, object dto) => {
    var cookies = httpRes.CookiesAsDictionary();
    string cookie;
    if (cookies.TryGetValue(ServiceStack.Keywords.SessionId, out cookie))
    {
        httpRes.DeleteCookie(ServiceStack.Keywords.SessionId);
        httpRes.SetCookie(new Cookie(mySessionIdentifier, cookie));
    }
});
```

You could also [suggest here](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) that this is configurable.

Comment: Would it lead to any performance penalty making it a static non const property?

Comment: @joelharkes I am assuming your talking about the `SessionId` in `SessionFeature.cs`: I think it's only a `const` because nobody has put forward a case to make it configurable. So I'd imagine it would be easily changed to a `static` property, and user configurable without performance penalty. There are a couple of places where the cookie id has been baked into the client and the ServerSendEvents feature that would need updating, but if the suggestion is put forward this sort of change usually happens quickly.

Comment: I think the best case to make it configurable is security: the cookie names could indicate a service stack backend. This would make it easier for a hacker to target the system.

Comment: @joelharkes I can see that argument and think that is a valid reason - I am for making it configurable. Just remember that there is a lot of other built in functionality in the ServiceStack service which will expose the server as being ServiceStack (default error pages, format of exceptions, default 'sync' routes, metadata, server headers, built-in files such as ss-utils.js). So there are a lot of aspects to hide, and this is just security through obscurity, there will always be aspects that expose the backend.

Comment: Allowing it to be configurable would break clients that set the Session Cookies explicitly. There's value in having agreed on constants that can be relied upon, esp. when they're used across process boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

A further case for configurable cookie names is that you may have say an MVC site at domain.com and an api at api.domain.com. If you take advantage of servicestack's session capabilities in both (but with separate logins), the ss-id etc cookies will fight each other on the two sites. This is the case in IE and Edge, where domain and subdomain cookies are always shared, whereas in Chrome the cookies remain separate.

We have exactly this configuration - an MVC site at domain.com, and various subdomains hosting apis for variations of our app. As soon as someone used IE rather than Chrome this broke the separate of cookies between the MVC site and the subdomains.

Unfortunately the filter solution above does not work for the servicestack MVC integration. It is too late for us to switch from domain.com to www.domain.com so we cannot currently enjoy servicestack's session storage on the MVC site.

I have requested the feature change.